# 2D terrain with midpoint displacement and collision

Tags: xna, collision-detection, monogame, terrain

I followed this theory [Here](http://www.somethinghitme.com/2013/11/11/simple-2d-terrain-with-midpoint-displacement/) to implement a simple scrolling 2D terrain for my running game. I am used to dealing with collision via a tile system but am looking for a good theory on how to perform terrain collision (keeping the player on-top the land) with a midpoint displacement 2D terrain

I am not worried about the physics aspect but how to determine if a character intersects an array of points generated by the theory above. Example if I have an array of points

```
Points[]
```

these points are used to draw lines to make a terrain. Now in my mind I would first find the player center. Take the center X and see which two points it is between. So if X is 4.6 lets say it is between points that lay on X=3 and X=6.

```
Player X = 4.6
Point1 X = 3, Y = 3
Point2 X = 6, Y = 5
```

So now knowing this I somehow need to calculate  what Y would be giving that X = 4.6. And once I have Y ensure that the Player Y > CalculatedY. If it is not push the player up to what Y the player should be.

So I guess what I a saying is

```
X = 3, Y = 3
X = 6, Y = 5
X = 4.6, Solve for Y
```

Comment: Could you please give more details about the physics, code examples, etc.? I would love to give an answer, but I'd have to create values and concepts out of nowhere...

Comment: I think code samples would make the question too specific. Keep it general and just describe at a high level the kind of geometry being created and how you're storing it.

Comment: updated with some more logic to try and clear things up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that the player collides with the ground only on the middle point.

We can do an approximation of the height of the terrain at a given point with this:

```
double x = 4.6;
double relativeX = x / widthBetweenPoints;
int terrainIndex = Math.floor(x);
double ratio = relativeX - terrainIndex;
int y = Points[terrainIndex] * (1 - ratio) + Points[terrainIndex + 1] * ratio;
```

Where

> x is the x position of the Player, in pixels.
>
> relativeX is the position of the player scaled down to the array, so that we know on which cell of the array he stands.
>
> widthBetweenPoints is the width, in pixels, between the array points.
>
> terrainIndex is the cell the player is standing on (1 in this case). In fact, the player stands between cell 1 and 2, but we round down to 1.
>
> ratio is where the player stands between the two points (here, 1 and 2, and the ratio is 30%)
>
> Points[] is the array containing the y values of the points or the terrain.

More in details:

1. We start by scaling the x value of the player down to the size of the terrain. If the x value of the player is 4.6 and the width between 2 points of the terrain is 2, then the relative position is 1.3. The player between point 1 and 2 of the terrain (with index starting at 0) and is at 70% towards 1 and 30% towards 2. More visual: 1 - - P - - - - - - 2
2. Then, we extract the current terrain index by getting the integer part of the relative x value and extract the ratio of "in between" by getting the floating part.
3. We then multiply the y value of the terrain at cell 1 by 70% and the value of cell 2 by 30%.

Just watch out that terrainIndex + 1 does not go out of bounds of the array.

Then you can apply as much physics or collisions as you want.